# VSTO How to set XlCalculationManual?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, vsto

I'm making VSTO Excel Addin which add a Excel worksheet and set values in the worksheet, when a ribbon button is clicked.

It works well, when the Active WorkBook does not have so much functions.
But when it comes to the WorkBook with much funcionts, it gets very slow.

I think the problem lies in the calculation method of the WorkBook.

1. Make another WorkBook object and a WorkSheet object then Copy the WorkSheet to the original WorkBook.
2. Change calculation method.

I tried following solutions, but it does not work.

```
private void A2_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        var activeSheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
        var thisworkbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook as Excel.Workbook;
        string linesheetname =  DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss");
        thisworkbook.Worksheets.Add(After: activeSheet);
        activeSheet = thisworkbook.ActiveSheet;
        activeSheet.Name = linesheetname;
        string[] rowstr = {//about 1000 elements in here};
        for (int i = 0; i < rowstr.Length; i++)
        {
            activeSheet.Cells[i + 1, 1] = rowstr[i];
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < 1001; j++)
        {
            activeSheet.Cells[1, j + 1] = j;
        }
    }
```

This program takes too much time to complete.
Is it possible to change Calculation Method within the WorkBook?
Is there other ways to add worksheet  and to set values in cells very quickly?
How can I solve this?

Comment: I've solved this problem.

Add following methods
thisworkbook.application.Calculation = Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual;
thisworkbook.application.Screenupdating = false;